# limit and derivative question

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives

for $f(x)=x \log(e+\frac{1}{x}) (x>0)$ ,
answer this questions: 
1.) $\alpha=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} ⁡{\frac{f(x)}{x}}$, find $\alpha$

2.) from result $\alpha$ from number 1, $\beta=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} ⁡{(f(x)-\alpha(x))}$ and $t=\frac{1}{x}$, $x\to \infty$ and $t\to 0^+$
find $\beta$

3.) from result $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in number 1 and 2, find $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} ⁡\frac{f(x)-(\alpha x+\beta)}{\frac{1}{x}}$

attempt:

1.)$\alpha=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} ⁡{\frac{f(x)}{x}}$= $\frac{x \log(e+\frac{1}{x}) }{x}=\log(e+\frac{1}{x})$=$\log e$ 
2.) $\beta=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} ⁡{(f(x)-\alpha(x))}$,
if $t=\frac{1}{x}$ , then $x\to\infty$ $t\to0$, change limit to $t$

$\beta=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} ⁡{(f(x)-\alpha(x))}$=$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} ⁡{x\log(e+\frac{1}{x})-x \log e}$
$=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} ⁡{\frac{1}{t}\ln(e+t)-\frac{1}{t}\ln e}$
=$$\beta=\lim\limits_{t \to 0}{\frac{\ln(\frac{e+t}{e})}{t}}=0$$

3.) from $\alpha $ and $\beta$ in number 1 and 2 
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} ⁡\frac{f(x)-(\alpha x+\beta)}{\frac{1}{x}}$ = $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} ⁡\frac{x (\ln(e+1/x)-\ln e}{\frac{1}{x}}$
and change to $t=\frac{1}{x}$, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} ⁡\frac{\ln(\frac{e+t}{e})}{t^2}$= $\infty$

however im not sure with this result, because i got $\infty $ in third one. is my attempt correct? thanks so much!!!

Comment: I assume $\log e=1$?

Comment: And instead of -> use \implies or \rightarrow inside the dollar signs. They produce $\implies$ and $\rightarrow$ respectively.

Comment: ok thanks! if i change $\log e=1$, will it change the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **point 1**, you can't do this step in this way

$$\color{red}{\alpha=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {\frac{f(x)}{x}}= \frac{x \log(e+\frac{1}{x}) }{x}=\log(e+\frac{1}{x})=\log e}$$

indeed you should write

$$\alpha=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {\frac{f(x)}{x}}= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{x \log(e+\frac{1}{x}) }{x}=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \log(e+\frac{1}{x})=\log e=1$$

For **point 2** note that

$$\beta=\lim\limits_{t \to 0^+}{\frac{\ln(\frac{e+t}{e})}{t}}=\lim\limits_{t \to 0^+}\frac1e\cdot{\frac{\ln(1+ \frac{t}e)}{\frac{t}e}}=\frac1e$$

For **point 3** note that

$$\frac{x\log(e+\frac{1}{x}) -(x+\frac1e)}{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{\log(e+t) -\left(1+\frac{t}{e}\right)}{t^2}=\frac{\log e+\log \left(1+\frac{t}{e}\right) -\left(1+\frac{t}{e}\right)}{t^2}=\frac{1+\log \left(1+\frac{t}{e}\right) -\left(1+\frac{t}{e}\right)}{t^2}=\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{t}{e}\right) -\frac{t}{e}}{t^2}\to-\frac1{2e^2}$$

indeed for $y\to0$

$$\log(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+o(y^2)\implies \log \left(1+\frac{t}{e}\right) =\frac{t}{e}-\frac{t^2}{2e^2}+o(t^2)$$

and

$$\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{t}{e}\right) -\frac{t}{e}}{t^2}=\frac{\frac{t}{e}-\frac{t^2}{2e^2}+o(t^2)-\frac{t}{e}}{t^2}=-\frac1{2e^2}+o(1)\to\frac1{2e^2}$$

Comment: thanks but i just realized in point 2, if i continue and not substitute $\log e=1$ then $\beta=\lim\limits_{t \to 0}{\frac{ln(\frac{e+t}{e})}{t}}$ = $\lim\limits_{t \to 0}{{ln(1+\frac{t}{e})}}^{\frac{1}{t}}$, if i assume  that $\frac{t}{e}=u$ then $\beta=\lim\limits_{u \to 0}{ln(1+u)}^{\frac{1}{eu}}$ = $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$, is this same as $\frac{1}{e}?

Comment: @Vixf $$\beta=\lim\limits_{u \to 0}{\ln(1+u)}^{\frac{1}{eu}}= \ln e^{\frac1e}=\frac1e$$

Comment: ok thanks!! hahaha i forgot the log

Comment: @Vixf You are welcome! When possible try always to use standard limit in the most basic form. What about point 3?

Comment: for point 3, is it 0? i dont need to count the limit, because it is $\beta-\beta$ (?)

Comment: @Vixf I've just added the solution, I've solved by Taylor's expansion but you can also use l'Hopital

Comment: thankyou so much for the detailed explanation!!! i've never use taylor expansion to find limit, but i want to try that, can you explain how can i get $o(y^2)$? and why only use the first two terms?  thanks!

Comment: @Vixf the little-o notation is used to handle the reminder from taylor's expansion, $o(t^2)$ means that the remainder is a term of order higher than $t^2$. You need to practice to can handle these terms. There not exist a general rule to determine a priori how many terms you need to consider, it is a matter of experience and practice. In this case the $t^2$ at the denominator suggest that an order 2 suffices. In general if you add more term respect the minimum you never will be wrong, but the limit could became  a mess.

Comment: ok thankyou so much!!!! the term is related to $x$ that after subtitute $t \rightarrow 0$ it will become $0$? so thats why only first two terms(?)

Comment: @Vixf with only 1 term you should have $o(t)/t^2$ and you could not conlcude anything.